# Python: Creating thousands of objects and passing a lookup dict to each one

Tags: python

I have a use case where I need to create thousands (sometimes hundreds of thousands) of objects from a class I create. To generate some of these objects variables, I need access to some look up tables. For example `self.order_location = self.order_locations[order_id]`

My concern here is I don't want to pass the same lookup table to 100s of thousands of objects and for them to create duplicates of them for each object or to slow anything down. Is passing these lookup tables when instantiating the class correct or should I be generating the likes of order_location before instantiating the object and then passing it to the object? I just prefer to have that logic in the class for that object.

EDIT:

I can't create a class attribute since the lookup table is created dynamically and pulled from a remote source while the job is running. Could I dynamically set the class attribute while the program is running once I have the look up tables? or is this bad practice?

Thanks

Comment: Is it reasonable to simply make the look-up tables a class attribute?  This would give you one copy, accessed by all the objects in common.

Comment: "My concern here is I don't want to pass the same lookup table to 100s of thousands of objects and for them to create duplicates of them for each object" - I don't see where any duplicates would be created. Are you under the impression that parameter passing copies objects in Python? You may want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: Python does *not* copy when you assign to a variable.

Comment: @Prune The lookup tables are created dynamically in a step before I start instantiating my objects and are dependant on some config parameters passed at the start of the job.

Comment: Thank you for confirming Python doesn't copy when assigning to to a variable. I just wasn't sure since it's being passed to multiple objects. Are there any performance implications then?

Comment: Can I pass the lookup tables once I have them generated like so:

`MyClass.order_locations = my_order_locations`

And then start creating my objects? Is this bad practice or better than passing the lookup table a million times every time I am creating an object?